# Duplicate ids impact

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

Have the following doubts in JQM:

1.If we use duplicate ids in separate html files what is the impact in jquery mobile.

1. Say if we have duplicate ids in separate html files, but if we are not using the id for anything, will it affect.
2. If we use a unique selector in javascript by way of some hierarchy, is it okay to have duplicate ids in separate html files

Am concerned over this because, i am using the same html file to load it in different pages using ajax. Since the ids will be same in this case, and both of them will be in the DOM, what is the impact. Or, should i create a separate file by changing the id and use that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Intro :

Lets start from the beginning, you probably know how jQuery Mobile handles pages but some other readers may not.

Basically jQuery Mobiles uses div elements with attribute data-role="page" to represent pages visible to user. Only one page can be seen at a given moment (some plugins can provide more but this is not a point of this question) thus creating a illusion of multilayered application. More then one page can be loaded into the DOM, among other benefits this will provide us with nice page transition effects.

### Answers :

1. Use of duplicate id's in jQuery Mobile, if used properly don't have any bad impact. But there is always an exception to the rule. Pages MUST have unique id's. That means that you can have pages with a same id but you will only be able to access first instance. All other page elements can have a same id, jQuery Mobile don't care as long as you watch carefully what you are doing.
2. Like in answer 1. it doesn't matter if you have same id's in a separate html files or in one large html file, as long as page id's are unique. Again, you can load another html file with a page that have a same id as a page already loaded into the DOM but as soon as you try to access something in it you will access page that was initially stored into the DOM. So no point in using it like this.
3. Again only rule is that page's must have unique id's. You can have as much other identical id's as long as they are child to a page container.

This all may be confusing but bear with me. To remedy this problem jQuery developers have created an unique selector that will help you get an active page. This is important because if we have page content that is same among pages (of course page id is unique) only way we can access or current page content if we do it with some active page selector.

**Example:**

```
$.mobile.activePage
```

This is an active page selector, it is basically an object that holds whole active page, so you can use it to change active page content, for example:

```
$.mobile.activePage.find('[data-role="content"]').append(......);
```

Then if you want to access other page identical content you would do it like this:

```
$('#pageID').find('[data-role="content"]').append(......);
```

### Conclusion

It doesn't matter if you have identical pages with identical content as long as pages have unique ID's.

Comment: Thanks for making it clear that only page id's need to be unique. Not the other ids.

Answer (score 1):

I have just spent 6 hours debugging an issue where the duplicate ids are significant.

Each page has a header with a button that pops up a menu panel. Every page gives it the id 'navpanel'.

Now one page wants to hide the button. In the pageShow event it says

```
$("#navpanel").toggle(user.isRegistered());
```

But the element with id navpanel that is found by the selector is the one in the page we have just left, not the one we are navigating to, with very very hard to track down consequences (I'm writing this at 2:14 in the morning having just worked it out).